# SocketExeption while running flutter

Tags: flutter, socketexception

"Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: OS Error: The remote computer refused the network connection.

, errno = 1225, address = localhost, port = 63798
"

this is showing when im running the app in emulator

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Android emulator and trying to access a backend running on your computer (localhost), you must use IP address 10.0.2.2.

Comment: Where to use/change this ip address?